# After installing Ubuntu, partitions do not match mounted directories

Tags: partition, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed an Ubuntu server in a virtual machine. What I really don't understand is the differences between parted and the mounted file system.

I allocated a 100GB disk in vmware and it seems to be split in 3.

Can someone explain this ?

```
$ cd /
$ sudo df -h

Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/hostname--vg-root   36G  1.7G   32G   6% /
udev                            32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs                          6.3G  240K  6.3G   1% /run
none                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            32G     0   32G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                      236M   33M  191M  15% /boot


$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   107GB  107GB  extended
 5      257MB   107GB  107GB  logical                lvm
```

is it related to LVM stuff?

I asked the installer to use the entire disk, but I don't remember if I asked to setup LVM's maybe I should not have.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration works but it's a bit messed up.

The output of `parted` shows that you have just 2 usable partitions:

```
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
```

This is the boot partition.

```
 2      257MB   107GB  107GB  extended
 5      257MB   107GB  107GB  logical                lvm
```

This is the main (root) partition, using LVM, contained inside an extended partition. It was unnecessary to create it as such -- you could have created it as a primary partition, especially since it uses LVM so you aren't limited by the "only 4 primary partitions" rule.

There's a Logical Volume of 36G that has been created inside the Volume Group that includes the 107-Gb Physical Volume. The rest of the space in the Volume Group hasn't been used and is wasted; you should either increase the size of the existing LV, or create another LV e.g. to mount in `/home`.

The output of `df` shows that the boot partition and the Logical Volume are respectively mounted on `/boot` and `/`, as it should be:

```
/dev/sda1                      236M   33M  191M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/hostname--vg-root   36G  1.7G   32G   6% /
```

and the other entries are just pseudo filesystems in RAM:

```
udev                            32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs                          6.3G  240K  6.3G   1% /run
none                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            32G     0   32G   0% /run/shm
```

Comment: in conclusion I should use guided - use entire disk instead of LVM..I dont know why ubuntu wizard wastes disk space like that

Comment: admin, btw, it's vmware :-)

Comment: damned, using regular install does not solve the problem.I dont understand why ubuntu install is not using the whole drive...

Comment: ok I redid a manual install and that did it.apparently ubuntu installer was creating a swap of 56gb to fit the ram I allocated to that machine, just insane